# Monsters overcoming magical damage reduction

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The d20srd states, under [Damage Reduction](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm):

> Some monsters are vulnerable to magic weapons. Any weapon with at
>   least a +1 magical enhancement bonus on attack and damage rolls
>   overcomes the damage reduction of these monsters. Such creatures’
>   natural weapons (but not their attacks with weapons) are treated as
>   magic weapons for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction.

Does this mean that practically no other creatures' natural weapons count as magical for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction: X/magic, only that of those who explicitly have damage reduction: X/magic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is correct.  Earlier - 2e maybe?- monsters counted as "+X" by virtue of high hit dice, but this is no longer the case.  Of course, that's why DR was softened from a flat "+1 or better to hit" to just reduction of damage.